# Row to column multiplication of unequal sized matrix in R

Tags: r

I am trying to multiply two data frames in R. I am trying to multiply the row to a respective column of the second data frame.

```
> df1
        Per_Day_Wage
[1] Jhon    25
[2] Sam 65
[3] Bob 16
[4] Laurance 14

> df2
      Jhon Sam  Bob Laurance
[1] Jan 15  18  26  89
[2] Feb 19  25  68  25
[3] Mar 79  251 89  82
[4] Apr 49  85  26  15
[5] May 12  25  68  25
[6] Jun 98  251 75  82
[7] Jul 25  558 85  33
[8] Aug 15  25  68  25
[9] Sep 12  89  8   82
[10] Oct    25  558 85  33
[11] Nov    19  95  19.8    89
[12] Dec    15  85  98  85
```

`df1 %*% df2` won't works `( getting an error '*' only defined for equally-sized data frames)`.

Comment: Please `dput` your example data. It appears that you are not working with `data.frames` as you claim, but rather with matrices. The structure of the underlying data is critical to providing a useful answer.

Comment: `t(df1*t(df2))` is the answer you are looking for

Comment: If they are dataframes, you perhaps need `as.matrix(df2) %*% as.matrix(df1)`